# How to add 2 decimal places having 0s to an array

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal

I want to print precision of 2 for all elements in my array.

For example, if I input 11.00, I expect output:

```
[11.00, 11.04, 11.09, 11.15, 11.19, 11.22]
```

but I get:

```
[11.0, 11.04, 11.09, 11.15, 11.19, 11.22]
```

Where the first element is missing trailing zero.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Main{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    float a=s.nextFloat();
    float arr[]= new float[6];
    // arr[0]=Float.valueOf((df.format(a+0.001)));
    arr[0]=a;
    arr[1]=a+(float)(0.04);
    arr[2]=a+(float)(0.09);
    arr[3]=a+(float)(0.15);
    arr[4]=a+(float)(0.19);
    arr[5]=a+(float)(0.22);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with why doesn't it work? From `Arrays.toString` docs:

> Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(float).

The implementation of `String.valueOf(float)` is:

```
public static String valueOf(float f) {
    return Float.toString(f);
}
```

Therefore the `df` declared in your code snippet is never used.

What can you do? As @Koenigsberg mentioned in his answer, you can iterate over the array, and then add brackets on the sides, and commas between the elements.

If you can use double instead of floats, you can use java streams. Code sample will be:

```
System.out.println("[" + Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(df::format).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]");
```

If you can't use doubles, you can just iterate over the indices of `arr`:

```
System.out.println("[" + IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> df.format(arr[i])).collect(Collectors.joining( ", ")) + "]");
```

Answer (score 1):

The object type in your array is a `float`. You cannot tell it to be a float with `N` decimal places, it is just a primitive value.

Typically you want to format the primitive when you need to use it, *e.g.*  as a `String`.

In this case:

```
for( float f : arr )
{
    System.out.println( df.format( f ) );
}
```

Comment: That is not the expected output. What about the delimiters? The brackets?

Comment: Adding pretty-print is trivial. OPs question is on how to add decimal points to floating point numbers. The key aspect of my answer is not the provided code, but to highlight that strings are being formatted, while decimal point representations are not inherent to `float` primitives.